# How can I enclose and cover a well in a driveway?

Tags: driveway, well

I have a well that is currently enclosed in a large, unsightly manner with a 1/2" steel sheet. I am having the driveway redone and I want to redo this so it is just a round hole with a cover. How can I approach this without buying one of those super heavy concrete pipes? Can I use brick for the wall of the hole? I only need the hole to be around 15" in diameter. The hole is about 3 feet deep currently.

Here is what it currently looks like under the steel cover. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would be careful in a driveway. Septic tanks are notorious pit traps for service trucks driving on lawns, and most drivers will assume a driveway is safe. Cement mixers, bucket trucks from arborists or utility companies, plumber vans full of parts and fittings; there are endless possibilities for getting people annoyed with you when their truck falls through your driveway.

Comment: @MatthewGauthier I'm not sure what you are referring to. This is for a well not a septic tank. Also, are you talking about the state that it is currently in or if I change it? This is why I'm looking for advice, I don't want to cause problems with vehicles running over the cover in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those concrete pipes are surprisingly inexpensive.  Get one that they have a man-hole cover to match.

Comment: I was actually hoping to avoid getting one altogether. Any idea on an alternative method?

Comment: The questions specifically asks for alternative approaches.

Comment: They are universally used in that application.